# How many parallel connections can be made for a single generic users?

Tags: data-loader

I have a downstream system which will take data from SFDC to Snowflake through Talend Job. But I am connecting to SFDC through one generic user. Is there any limit on haw many jobs I can parallely run with a single user? My observation is if am trying to run more 5 jobs I am getting some error:

Error Message:

```
java.io.IOException: [InvalidQueryLocatorFault [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR” exception Message='invalid query locator'"
```

I checked on the error code as well but somehow not able to connect these both. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Some detail on this subject [Designing Force.com Applications That Avoid Hitting Concurrent Request Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/force-com-concurrent-request-limits.html). Note that this is from 2013 so the limit values may well have changed by now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [API Request Limits and Allocations - Concurrent API Request Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm):

> Limits for various types of orgs for concurrent requests (calls) with
>   a duration of 20 seconds or longer:
>
> Developer Edition and Trial orgs: 5
>
> Production orgs and Sandboxes: 25

Answer (score 1):

There are no limit of number of parallel connections can be made using same user however other limits still apply.

1. Login calls per hour is 3600. That is quite a lot but you'd surprised how many bad implementations are there which logins each time it makes a call and one such mistake can block access for other integrations.
2. When a user is shared and you login two different apps, they both get same session id. So one of them logs out, it logs out for other apps. This is not an issue as long as apps are designed to handle the session  timeout and renegotiate the session.
3. More important issue, data access. Usually no two integrations have same access needs but when you share a user, you have to give more common access that satisfies both apps so you are giving more access than necessary for each app.